# xorg performance in openoffice

Tags: xorg, performance, cpu, openoffice

I've just been monitoring my cpu usage in openoffice calc when cells have been copied vs when they haven't and seen a dramatic increase in cpu usage for the Xorg process. The additional rendering required is a box with scrolling dashed lines around the cells that have been copied. The issue stands regardless of whether the window is minimised.
Obviously it takes /some/ cpu power to render, but to increase an i7 by a more or less constant 7% usage seems slightly overkill. If anything surely this should impact on the gpu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that turning off "Anti-Aliasing" speeds up OpenOffice on my system.  The setting is in Tools->Options, OpenOffice.org->View.  You might also want to experiment with turning on and off Hardware Acceleration.

Comment: worked a treat - on my laptop (1.4 core2) it took cpu usage down from a constant 20% to 3% :D. Thankyou!

Comment: Ditto here. Running Debian Squeeze on Atom 1.6, 2 GB RAM, Nvidia ION running nvidia proprietary driver. LibreOffice 3.4.3 from backports.org. As soon as I selected 2 cells and the running ants appeared, the Xorg CPU load peaked to 100% which rendered the machine unusable. Hardware acceleration is turned on. When I turned *off* anti-aliasing, everything went back to normal.

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment to help SEO because I was trying to troubleshoot high xorg cpu usage on my ubuntu 16.04 install - and went down numerous paths before realising (to my surprise) that the marching ants was causing the problem - this worked perfectly.

Before applying this fix, I noticed the process `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg --core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch` was using 30-40% cpu