# Improving OpenOffice speed

Tags: performance, openoffice

I'm looking for some tips and tricks on how to improve the performance of OpenOffice on my desktop. Any ideas, tutorials or articles on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but just use Gnumeric and Abiword instead. ;-)

Comment: This question is not appropriate here because it is too vague. If you have a specific performance problem with OpenOffice, we can help you with that. But this site is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about), it's not appropriate for “tips and tricks”.

Comment: This question is being [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/522572#522572).

Comment: Perhaps this might help?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/xorg-performance-in-openoffice/

Comment: NOTE: Oracle has dumped OpenOffice - http://goo.gl/cKzQS - so you might want to consider switching to LibreOffice, essentially the same thing. http://www.libreoffice.org/

Answer (score 1):

Im not using it anymore but there are some tips:

- reduce graphics cache (number of objects and memory per object)

- turn off font preview in font list

- turn off icons in menus

- reduce cache wherever is possible

I know that it may sound generic but it helps and speeds up OpenOffice a little (i used it in v2.x and v3.0). If you find OOo too heavy, try to use GoogleDocs online (if you have broadband connection) in smaller browser window (it speeds up drawing of all elements in browser so try to use it in non-full screen).

Answer (score 0):

Does your harddisk-LED burn after startup of OOorg? Then you're probably depending on swap, which is always slow. Buy more RAM if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found OpenOffice (& other apps) disk intensive, so used the brute force approach of buying an SSD and placing appropriate partitions on it.